# C# Chat application

Tags: c#

Hello i have a chat application and do not understand where im going wrong, what im doing is just doing a timer every second it update the messages, m iageva  static int witch = 1 or = 0 to update the messages.. when they send a new message it updates it to 1 the code is weird, sometime i get all the messages twice or sometimes they dont send
 i just wanted to know if there was any other way of doing this that any of you knew such as tutorials or advice
 my code:

MY CODE FOR INSERT MESSAGES ON BUTTON PRES!!

```
using (SqlDatabaseClient client = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
{
    int id = int.Parse(client.ExecuteScalar("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM program_messages").ToString());
    client.SetParameter("id", id + 1);
    client.SetParameter("sender", mUsername);
    client.SetParameter("message", textBox1.Text);
    client.SetParameter("timesent", DateTime.Now);
    client.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO program_messages (`id`,`sender`,`message`,`timesent`) VALUES (@id,@sender,@message,@timesent)");
}
updateneeded = 1;
```

MY CODE FOR REFRESH MESSAGES

```
using (SqlDatabaseClient client6 = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
{
    int id = int.Parse(client6.ExecuteScalar("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM program_messages").ToString());
    int finalcount = listBox2.Items.Count;
    foreach (DataRow row2 in client6.ExecuteQueryTable("SELECT * FROM program_messages").Rows)
    {
        if (updateneeded > 0)
        {
            if (!listBox2.Items.Contains((string)row2["sender"] + ": " + (string)row2["message"]))
            listBox2.Items.Add((string)row2["sender"] + ": " + (string)row2["message"]);
        }
    }
    updateneeded = 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. I wouldn't use timers but events 2. Your approach allows SQL injection

Comment: @Robert and what *event* would you recommend he subscribe to? You could use `SqlDependency`, however, I would say polling is the correct way to do this.

Comment: I get where robert is coming from, i think he means refresh the messages on the button press so it knows when theres a new message to show, witch is a better idea then timers.

Comment: 1. I wouldnt do a chat with SQL, but over TCP/UDP. 2. You shouldnt use the local datetime from the computer, since it could be different between Clients its better to use the Server datetime.

Comment: You need an auto-increment column instead of doing that yourself

Comment: @James: In Zain's scenario I would implement a notifying mechanism, so that the DB tells its client about changes. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx This saves you a lot of overhead and makes the UI exerience way more smooth.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the culprit:

```
using (SqlDatabaseClient client = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
{
    int id = int.Parse(client.ExecuteScalar("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM program_messages").ToString());
    client.SetParameter("id", id + 1);
    // ...
    client.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO program_messages (`id`,`sender`,`message`,`timesent`) VALUES (@id,@sender,@message,@timesent)");
}
updateneeded = 1;
```

You should make that `id` column an `IDENTITY` and let SQL handle it. That way, you can remove your first `SELECT` statement and perform a single query. 
Also, you should also make your `timesent` and automatically generated value (through `GETDATE()`), so it's consistent across all clients.

Your code would become:

```
using (SqlDatabaseClient client = SqlDatabaseManager.GetClient())
{
    client.SetParameter("sender", mUsername);
    client.SetParameter("message", textBox1.Text);
    client.ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO program_messages ('sender','message','timesent') VALUES (@sender,@message,GETDATE())");
}
updateneeded = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a tutorial i would suggest you that video(s) [C# chat application](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObcGBT4ZWEU)

you will go over the following points:

TCP/IP Chat

Basic Client/Server

winforms IP address

wcf

sockets

it helped me alot!

Comment: Is that just for you your pc) or multiple users?

Comment: Multiple, a chat program for 1 is useless ;)

Answer (score 0):

I actually just did this myself not too long ago. And P2P is the way to go. I'm not sure why you would want the chat logs saved to a database for anyone to look at anyway. but here check this out!

[WCF Chat example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb690929%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Logging the messages could be useful for any number of reasons in which you want to see the history of a chat and you were not one of the participants

Comment: True, but in my experience most people are less politically correct when they're talking through key strokes. If they're unknowingly being recorded it has more potential for harm than good. IMHO.

Comment: The classic "This call is being recorded for quality assurance" comes to mind, so for a business that makes a lot of sense to record chats.